# Primes $p_i$ such that $\sin(\frac{\pi}{n})\sin(\frac{p_1\pi}{n})\cdots\sin(\frac{p_k\pi}{n})$ is rational

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, trigonometry, prime-numbers

The following amazing identity can be checked directly by hand.
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{17\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{23\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{29\pi}{30}\right) = \frac{1}{2^8}
$$
This makes me wonder:

> **Question.** Can we find arbitrarily long sequences of prime numbers $p_1<p_2<\cdots<p_k$ such that the product
>   $$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{p_1\pi}{n}\right)\sin\left(\frac{p_2\pi}{n}\right)\cdots\sin\left(\frac{p_k\pi}{n}\right)$$
>   is rational for some integer $n>p_k$.

Other examples are:
$$\begin{align}
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{4}\right)\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{4}\right) &= \frac{1}{2} \\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{6}\right)\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{6}\right)\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{6}\right) &= \frac{1}{2^2} \\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right)\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{8}\right)\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{8}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{8}\right) &= \frac{1}{2^3} \\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{12}\right)\sin\left(\frac{2\pi}{12}\right)\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{12}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{12}\right)\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{12}\right) &= \frac{1}{2^5} \\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{18}\right)\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{18}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{18}\right)\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{18}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{18}\right)\sin\left(\frac{17\pi}{18}\right) &= \frac{1}{2^6} \\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{18}\right)\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{18}\right)\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{18}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{18}\right)\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{18}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{18}\right)\sin\left(\frac{17\pi}{18}\right) &= \frac{1}{2^7} \\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{17\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{23\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{29\pi}{30}\right) &= \frac{1}{2^8} \\
\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{17\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{23\pi}{30}\right)\sin\left(\frac{29\pi}{30}\right) &= \frac{1}{2^9}
\end{align}
$$
The longest I found is
$$\sin\left(\frac{\pi}{38}\right)\sin\left(\frac{3\pi}{38}\right)\sin\left(\frac{5\pi}{38}\right)\sin\left(\frac{7\pi}{38}\right)\sin\left(\frac{11\pi}{38}\right)\sin\left(\frac{13\pi}{38}\right)\sin\left(\frac{17\pi}{38}\right)\sin\left(\frac{19\pi}{38}\right)\sin\left(\frac{23\pi}{38}\right)\sin\left(\frac{29\pi}{38}\right) = \frac{1}{2^9}$$
Note that it breaks the pattern of $n=p_k+1$. Note also that not all examples have consecutive primes.

Comment: [Something to begin with](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649011/more-questions-from-mathematical-analysis-by-apostol/2649588#2649588) $$\prod\limits_{k = 1}^{n - 1} \sin \dfrac{k\pi}{n} = \dfrac{n}{2^{n - 1}}$$

Answer (score 12):

Consider a product:
$$
\prod_{m}^{}2\sin\frac{m}{n}\pi,
$$
where $m$ are integer numbers:
$$ 0<m< n.$$
As all multipliers are algebraic integers the product is rational if and only if it is integer.

This particularly happens if $m$ is a set of numbers coprime to $n$: $\gcd(m,n)=1$. It holds:
$$
P_n:=\prod_{m}^{\gcd(m,n)=1}2\sin\frac{m}{n}\pi=
\begin{cases}
1,& n\ne p^k\\
p,& n=p^k
\end{cases},\tag{1}
$$
where $p$ is a prime number, and $k$ is a positive integer. The expression (1) can be proved similarly to the result cited in a comment above, using [cyclotomic polynomials](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclotomic_polynomial) $\Phi_n(z)$ instead of $\frac{z^n-1}{z-1}$.

If *all* $m$ coprime to $n$ happen to be prime numbers we find an example of the set in question. This should however fail for large $n$. The next idea may be: let us try the product $P_kP_\ell$ for distinct $k,\ell$. This however does not work. Indeed, in accord with question the arguments of sines have to be reduced to common denominator $n=\frac{k\cdot\ell}{(k,\ell)}$. Since $k$ and $\ell$ are distinct at least one of them is not a divisor of the other. Without lost of generality we may assume it is $\ell$. Consider now the numerators $m_k$ which after reducing to common denominator $n$ are
$m_k\equiv m_k^{(n)}=m_k^{(k)}\frac{\ell}{(k,\ell)}$ (here $m^{(n)}$ means the value of the numerator for denominator $n$). Thus $m_k$ can be a prime number for $\frac{\ell}{(k,\ell)}\ne1$ only if $m_k^{(k)}=1$ and $\frac{\ell}{(k,\ell)}$ is a prime number. This is clearly impossible for *all* $m_k$ since $m_k^{(k)}$ (except for a single one) are distinct from $1$. The only exception is $P_2$ which consists of single factor $2\sin\frac12\pi=2$. Except for this case we cannot therefore use a product $P_k P_\ell$. By the same argument this is true for the products of a larger number of $P$'s as well.

After closer inspection of $(1)$ one can note that if $n$ is not a prime power one can use only half of sines picking up one from the pair ($\sin\frac{m}{n}\pi,\sin\frac{n-m}{n}\pi$) to obtain still integer result (equal to $1$). We denote such products as $Q_n$. Similarly to the case of $P_n$ there is an exceptional product $Q_6$ consisting of the single factor $2\sin\frac16\pi=1$.

Thus if $m$ are required to be prime or 1 the simplest possible combinations are
$$
P_n, Q_n,\tag{2}
$$
where the latter form can be used only if $n$ is not a prime power. If  $n=2p$ or $n=6p$ with $p$ being a prime number the expressions $(2)$ can be multiplied additionally by $P_2$ or $Q_6$, respectively.

And indeed all examples given in question are of the form $(2)$. In the same order as they appear in question, they can be symbolically represented as:
$$
P_4, P_6P_2, P_8, P_{12}Q_6, P_{18}, P_{18}Q_6, P_{30}Q_6, Q_{38} P_2.
$$

The reason for the equalities in question can be seen now in the already mentioned fact that the sets of $m$ coprime to given $n$ consist in all cases except for the last one  exclusively of prime numbers.

Considering in the case $n=38$ the table of coprimes to $38$:
$$
\begin{matrix}
1&3&5&7&9&11&13&15&17\\
37&35&33&31&29&27&25&23&21
\end{matrix},
$$
one easily observes that every pair contains at least one prime (observe that $38=2\cdot19$ is not a prime power).

The point of the above consideration is the following. The construction of long rational product of prime $m$ on these lines is hardly possible, as the list of numbers coprime to large $n$ cannot consist exclusively of prime numbers (in fact $n=30$ is the largest such number), and even the trick similar to the case $n=38$ will not work on a long run. Thus, the construction of very long sequences on the base of $(2)$ is impossible.

There exist however much longer sequences than those listed in question. The longest ones by numerical tests are:
$$
Q_{105}, Q_{140}, Q_{180}, Q_{210},
$$
all consisting of 24 multipliers. It can be claimed that there are no sequences of required structure for $n>210$.