# Compute $\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi j}{2 n}\right)$

Tags: complex-analysis, trigonometry

How can I evaluate $\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}\sin\left(\frac{\pi j}{2 n}\right)$ ? 
I know that without the factor $2$ one can take advantage of the roots of the unity, but in this case only the roots with positive imaginary parts are to be considered.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's the square root of $\prod_{j=1}^{2n-1}\sin(j\pi/2n)$. Can you do that one?

Comment: I can solve the productory you write, though it's not obvious to me that my expression is the square root of this one.

Comment: @GrazianoAmati Notice that the sin values are reflected across $\pi/2$. Therefore, the product from $j = 1 \to n-1$ is the same as the product from $j = n+1 \to 2n-1$

Comment: Try to follow this technique https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2649011/more-questions-from-mathematical-analysis-by-apostol/2649588#2649588