# How to prove $ \prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{n}}-1 \right) = (-1)^{n-1} n $

Tags: complex-analysis

how to prove the following equation?
$$
\prod_{k=1}^{n-1}\left(e^{i\frac{2k\pi}{n}}-1 \right) = (-1)^{n-1} n
$$

The product on the LHS is hard to calculate. The only progress I got is that each term on the LHS is the root of equation $(z+1)^n=1$.

Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the product of the roots of $(z+1)^n=1$ to prove that $\prod_{k=1}^{n-1} \sin\frac{k\pi}{n}=\frac{n}{2^{n-1}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3161493/using-the-product-of-the-roots-of-z1n-1-to-prove-that-prod-k-1n-1) [specifically, the answer by Robert Z]

Comment: Yes, beautiful and sweet answer. This question has been closed. Thanks for your comment.