Help understanding derivation of identity $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cot^4\left({k\pi\over 2n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{45}n(2n-1)(4n^2+10n-9)$
This question regards understanding some of the steps in the derivation of the identity for $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cot^4\left({k\pi\over 2n+1}\right)$
It is shown 1 that using Vieta's formula that
$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cot^4\left({k\pi\over 2n+1}\right)=\frac{1}{45}n(2n-1)(4n^2+10n-9)$
Since $\cot\left({k\pi\over 2n+1}\right)=\frac{i (\omega^k+1)}{\omega^k-1} .\tag{1}$
It follows that $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\cot^4\left({k\pi\over 2n+1}\right)=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{ \omega^k+1}{\omega^k-1})^4 .\tag{2}$
The source 1 goes on to say $P(x)=\frac{x^{2n+1}-1}{x-1} .\tag{3}$
will have roots $\omega,\omega^2..\omega^{2n}$ but I cannot understand why and how (4) is derived using $y=\frac{x+1}{x-1},x=\frac{y+1}{y-1}$?
$P(x)=\frac{(\frac{y+1}{y-1})^{2n+1}-1}{\frac{y+1}{y-1}-1} .\tag{4}$
1 brilliant

Why does (1) not contain $n$ on the right side? Is $\omega=\pi/(2n+1)$?

This is essentially based on Demoivre's theorem $\cos mt+i\sin mt=(\cos t+i\sin t) ^m$ for positive integers $m$. Use binomial theorem and equate imaginary parts and then replace $m=2n+1$.

See details at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2405451/72031

See also  https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3943914

That is the polynomial transformation of the roots to evaluate the sum of the fourth powers of $\frac{w^k+1}{w^k-1}=\frac{x_k+1}{x_k-1}=y_k$, where $k=1,2,\ldots,n$. To apply Vieta's formulas for the sum, it is necessary to transform the polynomial and roots. If $x=w,\ w^2,\ w^3,\ldots$ are the roots of the polynomial $P(x)$, then $y=\frac{w+1}{w-1},\ \frac{w^2+1}{w^2-1},\ \frac{w^3+1}{w^3-1},\ldots$ will be the roots of the polynomial $\mathcal P(y)=P\left(\frac{y+1}{y-1}\right)$ as $\frac{y+1}{y-1}=x\implies y=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$. You can apply Vieta's formulas to the polynomial $\mathcal P(y)$ to evaluate the required sum. I hope it clarifies and helps you understand it.

I see since $y=\frac{w+1}{w-1},\ \frac{w^2+1}{w^2-1},\ \frac{w^3+1}{w^3-1},\ldots$ is the form of cot what we are looking for; the transformation $\frac{y+1}{y-1}=x\implies y=\frac{x+1}{x-1}$ turns the polynomial into what is necessary to then apply Vieta's formula. Thank you.

Correct! I am glad you got it.
